# Get JavaScript errors coming from WKWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, wkwebview

I implemented the `WKScriptMessageHandler` protocol and I have defined the `userContentController(:didReceiveScriptMessage:)` method.

When there is a error in the Javascript, I get (in the `WKScriptMessage` object) something not really useful like:

```
{
    col = 0;
    file = "";
    line = 0;
    message = "Script error.";
    type = error;
}
```

On the other hand, if I open the Safari Web Inspector, I can see the real error which is (for instance):

`TypeError: FW.Ui.Modal.sho is not a function. (In 'FW.Ui.Modal.sho', 'FW.Ui.Modal.sho' is undefined)`

Is there a way to get that error back in my native code?

**EDIT:**
Just to clarify, the javascript code is written by a javascript developer (who doesn't have access to the native source code, so he can't debug the app via Xcode). The code he writes it's then pushed to the iOS app (downloaded from an enterprise app store).

Answer (score -1):

You can wrap the expression in a `try catch` block before evaluating it. Then have the JavaScript return the error message if it fails. Here is an example taken from the [Turbolinks-iOS adapter](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks-ios/blob/master/Turbolinks/WebView.swift#L67-L110), available on GitHub.

```
extension WKWebView {
   func callJavaScriptFunction(functionExpression: String, withArguments arguments: [AnyObject?] = [], completionHandler: ((AnyObject?) -> ())? = nil) {
        guard let script = scriptForCallingJavaScriptFunction(functionExpression, withArguments: arguments) else {
            NSLog("Error encoding arguments for JavaScript function `%@'", functionExpression)
            return
        }

        evaluateJavaScript(script) { (result, error) in
            if let result = result as? [String: AnyObject] {
                if let error = result["error"] as? String, stack = result["stack"] as? String {
                    NSLog("Error evaluating JavaScript function `%@': %@\n%@", functionExpression, error, stack)
                } else {
                    completionHandler?(result["value"])
                }
            } else if let error = error {
                self.delegate?.webView(self, didFailJavaScriptEvaluationWithError: error)
            }
        }
    }

    private func scriptForCallingJavaScriptFunction(functionExpression: String, withArguments arguments: [AnyObject?]) -> String? {
        guard let encodedArguments = encodeJavaScriptArguments(arguments) else { return nil }

        return
            "(function(result) {\n" +
            "  try {\n" +
            "    result.value = " + functionExpression + "(" + encodedArguments + ")\n" +
            "  } catch (error) {\n" +
            "    result.error = error.toString()\n" +
            "    result.stack = error.stack\n" +
            "  }\n" +
            "  return result\n" +
            "})({})"
    }

    private func encodeJavaScriptArguments(arguments: [AnyObject?]) -> String? {
        let arguments = arguments.map { $0 == nil ? NSNull() : $0! }

        if let data = try? NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(arguments, options: []),
            string = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as? String {
                return string[string.startIndex.successor() ..< string.endIndex.predecessor()]
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, this solution does not work in my scenario, where there is a javascript developer writing code on it's own computer, and then this code get pushed to the iOS app (downloaded for instance from an enterprise app store). The JS dev will not be able to see the right error (a syntax error in the example above), but just a generic "Script error." Am I correct?

Comment: Ah, gotcha. You are correct, this code is for evaluating scripts embedded in the iOS client. However, the same `try catch` mentality applies - just implement that code when developing the script.

Comment: it might works if the code is small. But if the code is thousands of lines of code you can't put everything in a `try catch` I guess. Also I'm not sure if the `try catch` works with syntactic errors like the one in my question: `try { result.sho(); catch (error) { ... };`